Optimizing Polling Times to Minimize Average Response Time Under Constraints
Background:
I am working on optimizing an RPC (Remote Procedure Call) server that handles a high volume of requests (around 200,000 QPS). Each incoming request follows this procedure:

Cache Check: If an identical request has been completed in the past, we directly return the cached result.
Request Execution: If the request has not started yet, we execute the request logic, mark its status as "in progress" atomically, and upon completion, mark it as "finished" and cache the response.
Concurrent Requests: If an identical request is already in progress (due to concurrency), we need to poll the cache until the result is available.

In step 3, since the service is managed by a Kubernetes cluster, we use a centralized Redis cache. Due to the high QPS, the number of cache polls significantly amplifies the load on the Redis cluster. To mitigate this, we have set a maximum number of polls, $x$, beyond which the cost of Redis operations becomes unsustainable. Additionally, we impose a maximum waiting time $T_{\text{max}}$ (e.g., 200 ms), ensuring that requests have bounded response times even in high-concurrency scenarios.
Problem:
Given:

A cumulative distribution function (CDF) $F(t)$ representing the empirical distribution of request completion times over a recent period. Here, $t$ is the time from request initiation to completion, and $F(t)$ is the fraction of requests that have completed within time $t$.
A maximum number of polls $x$.
A maximum waiting time $T_{\text{max}}$ (e.g., 200 ms).

We assume that the probability that a request has completed by time $t$ is approximated by $P(t) = F(t)$.
Objective:
Determine the optimal polling times $t_1, t_2, \dots, t_x$ within the interval $[0, T_{\text{max}}]$ that minimize the expected average response time for concurrent requests, under the following constraints:

Polling Constraints:

The number of polls is limited to $x$.
Polling times are non-decreasing: $0 \leq t_1 \leq t_2 \leq \dots \leq t_x \leq T_{\text{max}}$.


Response Time Definition:

The response time $S$ for a concurrent request is the time of the first poll at which the request is found to be completed, or $T_{\text{max}}$ if the request is still not completed after the last poll.



Mathematical Formulation:
We seek to minimize the expected response time $\mathbb{E}[S]$, where:
$$
\mathbb{E}[S] = \sum_{i=1}^{x} \left[ t_i \cdot \left( P(t_i) - P(t_{i-1}) \right) \right] + T_{\text{max}} \cdot \left( 1 - P(t_x) \right),
$$
with $P(t_0) = 0$ and $t_x \leq T_{\text{max}}$.
What I Know and What I Don't Understand:
I know how to express the expected response time mathematically and have derived the above formula. However, I am unsure how to optimally choose the polling times $t_1, t_2, \dots, t_x$ to minimize this expected value, given the constraints. I would appreciate any insights into methods or approximations that might help solve this optimization problem, especially considering the properties of the distribution $P(t)$.
What I've Tried:
So far, I've attempted to manually experiment with evenly spaced polling times, but this doesn't seem to be optimal, especially when $P(t)$ is not uniformly distributed. I suspect that more sophisticated optimization techniques are required, but I am unfamiliar with the relevant methods.
Additional Notes:

$P(t)$ is derived from empirical data and represents the completion probability of requests at time $t$.
The system is highly concurrent, and reducing both the average response time and Redis load is critical.
I would greatly appreciate any insights or references to similar problems in optimization or stochastic processes.

Example:
Suppose $P(t)$ is given, $x = 10$, and $T_{\text{max}} = 200$ ms. How should we choose $t_1$, $t_2$, ..., $t_{10}$ to minimize $\mathbb{E}[S]$?
